# Call a JS Method before JQGrid reload method is invoked

Tags: jqgrid

I want to call a javascript method before the JqGrid grid default refresh or reload  ..
can any help me

Thanks and advance
ravi

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the event beforeRequest

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: Hi Finaly Got the answer                     jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
  { edit:false,view:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,
    beforeRefresh: function(){
        alert('In beforeRefresh');
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
  });

Comment: In my case I needed to remove bootstrap's popover from some jqgrid cells (some of them were still appearing after a table refresh) and I can confirm using the beforeRequest and destroying the popovers inside this function solved my issue.

Comment: I realize this is a very old post but I need some help. I can get  the alert to work but I would like to change the contents of a div container in the function and I cannot get it to change. I can change the content at the loadComplete event.